# Create symbolic link in Linux guest on Windows host

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, symlink

I am running Virtualbox Linux 32 bit guest OS on a Windows 10 64 bit host OS. I am sharing a folder between the host (windows) and the guest (linux). When I am trying to create a symbolic link in the guest I am getting the following error:

```
ln -s file1 link1
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'link1': Operation not permitted
```

How can I enable the possibility of creating symbolic links by the Linux guest, on a Windows host, within a shared folder?

Answer (score 1):

I have called the `VBoxManage` program with the following arguments to fix the issue ([source](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2014/02/01/symlinks-within-shared-folders-virtualbox-operation-permitted-read-filesystem/)):

```
VBoxManage setextradata MACHINE_LABEL VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_LABEL 1
```

But now the error I receive is: `Protocol error` instead of `Operation not permitted`. To fix this issue, I had to run my VM from within the host as administrator. Is there a way to fix the permissions, so the VB image doesn't have to be run as admin?